# Classifying news articles by most probable subjects

Tags: python, nlp, classification, text-mining, text-parsing

Say I have an API that returns summaries of news articles from over 70 news publications. If I wanted to parse each summary and deduce the core subject matter, what sort of algorithms should I be researching?

Here is an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish:

> **Loss of sea ice accelerates warming, threatens animals and peoples
> living in the Arctic and raises global security concerns.**
>
> Polar sea ice melts each summer and reforms each winter—a freeze-thaw
> cycle that in the Arctic has been dramatically altered by global
> warming. Not only is summer sea ice shrinking rapidly in the Arctic,
> but so is the average thickness of sea ice. Where in the past, some
> Arctic sea ice grew to 10 feet (3 meters) thick over multiple years,
> now much of the ice has only one year of growth, making it much more
> susceptible to melting in the summer. Scientists project that the
> Arctic Ocean may be ice-free in summer in just a few decades.

```
Core subjects: ["sea ice melt", "arctic", "global warming"]
```

Comment: The most obvious solution I can see would be to use a machine learning classification algorithm.  You would need a training set of examples where you were given both the summaries and the correct labels (the subjects).  Use this training set to train your algorithm how to classify future examples.  Test the algorithm on a test set and adjust the algorithm and parameters as needed until you are satisfied with the accuracy on the test set.  Then set it loose in the wild on new examples.  A quick overview here: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html

Comment: @huck_cussler I'll check it out right now. I figured the solution would be some supervised ML algorithm, but I had no clue how to get started. Thanks!

Comment: @Kris Maybe you could investigate Information retrieval algorithm and specifically [Learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank).